# Decoding - from Java to Powershell

Tags: java, powershell, encryption

I have inherited a self-made certification solution based on Java and Microsoft SQL server. We are moving forward to a Venafi solution. The old certificate has to be moved from the old solution to a Venafi pki solution. The designer of the old solution is not here anymore, but I have the decryption part in Java, including the decryption key. I have absolutely no experience in Java, and very limited cryptographic experience in Powershell.

The Java  code  to decrypt is this:

```
SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.decode(encryptionkey.getBytes()), "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
```

The password is something like: gTsLrRTFR5Q0cvQZFRuZPw== (Not the actual password) and the certificates in encrypted format is basic hex data like 0x5F4E23E1 ... all in 1024 sizes.

How would I decrypt these certificates in powershell?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Two questions: you do have the encrypted certificate actually in a file available? Second: would a decryption in Java be ok for you? Which Java version would you use ?

Comment: Thank you. I have a decrypted version of  the certificate, and the encryptec certificate data, should be easy to get into a file :)  Decryption in Java wouldn't benefit me, unfortunately

Comment: so your problem is SOLVED ?

Comment: Ohh no.  I can do a manual extraction of a  certificate from the old application,  but since  we are moving 30.000 certificates,  it have to be scriptet.

Comment: Can you please provide a SAMPLE dataset so we are been able to find a routine that might help you (passwort is a string as you provided it, encrypted + decrypted certificate as best as they are (maybe in zipped-form and available with Google Drive or GitHub or any public service). I'm off for some hours now... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not the specialist for powershell so I can just give you some hints to run the decryption part, for tasks like "get all files in folder with ending *.enc"
I'm leaving it to you to find a solution.

Assuming you are having a key in the format

```
MTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQ1Ng==
```

then it is a Base64-encode key. If all of your 30.000 certificates were encrypted with the same key then simply get the hex encoded value of the key
using an online service like https://base64.guru/converter/decode/hex.

Just enter the string above and press convert Base64 to Hex and you receive the key as follows:

```
31323334353637383930313233343536
```

Now count the chars - here we have 32 chars that mean it is a 16 byte (128 bit) long key used for AES cryptography. It's not a joke to count them because
the length of the key is important for the decryption task.

Having a certificate-file that was encrypted with a 32-char long hex-key ("cert32.enc") you use openssl (can be used in powershell as well as in many
other scripting languages) with this command (**it is important to use the -K-option with a capital K** and the hexstring enclosed with quotation marks):

```
openssl enc -aes-128-ecb -d -in cert32.enc -out cert.pem -K "31323334353637383930313233343536"
```

This will decode you the original certificate to the file "cert.pem" as follows (it is a sample certificate !):

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Now we are working with the other key length (64 chars long). Having a base64 that looks like

```
MTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAxMjM0NTY3ODkwMTI=
```

you will get the hex-string with 64 characters:

```
3132333435363738393031323334353637383930313233343536373839303132
```

Now we are running the openssl-commandline with a similar algorithm (and another filename/key):

```
openssl enc -aes-256-ecb -d -in cert64.enc -out cert.pem -K "3132333435363738393031323334353637383930313233343536373839303132"
```

Voila, it's decoding to the same cert.pem as above.

All files are available via my GitHub repo for easy testing:

https://github.com/java-crypto/Stackoverflow/tree/master/Decoding_from_Java_to_Powershell

Comment: That did the trick. Shelling out to Openssl works. Thank you so much!